# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null at HTMLSpanElement.expand

Tags: javascript, html

Here I meet a small problem with my javascript code. I followed this tutorial for something quite simple to do (normally) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQW-MXriUIU&t=417s&ab_channel=CodewithAniaKub%C3%B3w%23JavaScriptGames

What I did :
Of course I adapted the HTML proposed in the tutorial to the visual result I wanted to obtain but I made sure to keep the right class and id attributes for my different elements.

On the other hand, I really used the same code in JS to make sure that everything is in accordance with the tutorial.

Here is the part of the HTML that interests us:

```
<div class="item">
          <a href="contact.html">
            <img src="img/services/service-5.jpg" alt="service" />
          </a>
          <div class="expandMoreContent" id="showMoreContent5">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
              adipisicing elit. Enim, suscipit. Eos tempora dolorem commodi
              consectetur consequatur repellat nam, sunt repudiandae maiores
              modi velit, in possimus nesciunt quas, dicta ullam ex.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="expandMoreHolder">
            <span
              expand-more
              data-hidetext="Less..."
              data-showtext="...Read More"
              data-target="ShowMoreContent5"
              class="btn-expand-more"
              >...Read more</span
            >
          </div>
          <a href="contact.html" class="btn-light">
            <i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i> Request a quote
          </a>
        </div>
```

And here is my javascript for the desired effect:

```
// Show and hide more or less text services

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const expandsMore = document.querySelectorAll('[expand-more]')

function expand() {
const showContent = document.getElementById(this.dataset.target)
  if(showContent.classList.contains('expand-more'))) { // Apparently the error is on this line, but I can't figure it out...
    this.innerHTML=this.dataset.showText
}else {
  this.innerHTML=this.dataset.hideText

}
showContent.classList.toggle('expand-active')
}
expandsMore.forEach(expandMore => {
  expandMore.addEventListener('click', expand)
})

})
```

What I want :
My goal, therefore, is to create a text toggle on the service div paragraph of my website.

What I get :

The problem is that I don't get any result except this error in my console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
at HTMLSpanElement.expand. I think something is stuck and prevents adding the "expand-active" class to my HTML elements to the line I commented in JS, but no way to understand what exactly it is. I used the same code from the tutorial at the beginning. And, it's a very recent tuto, so the obsolescence track is ruled out :)

I thank you for any suggestion that you could bring me !

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say Hello... So, Hello guys ! :D

Comment: `classList of null` means that the element you're trying to edit doesn't exist. Try a `console.log(showContent)` after `const showContent = document.getElementById(this.dataset.target)` to see if your element actually exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is that in html`<div class="expandMoreContent" id="showMoreContent5">` your id's first letter is in lowercase

in javascript you query for an element start with capital case

`data-target="ShowMoreContent5"`

`const showContent = document.getElementById(this.dataset.target)`

change either one , it will work.

plus: the code you paste here has another problem, a useless right bracket here,plese remove.

`if(showContent.classList.contains('expand-more'))) { // Apparently the error is on this line, but I can't figure it out...`

Comment: Oh god ! I've been on it since yesterday ! It works fine now, thanks !

Edit : The useless right brackets isn't in my original code. I don't where it came from but it's ok. Thanks again ! :)